# How can I get proper CDN link to import CreatableSelect from react-select/creatable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having issues utilizing the CreatableSelect Component. I can only use cdn files to load dependencies.
I am getting the following error :

`CreatableSelect is not defined`

I have used Select component from react-select with cdn links in the same application. For, Select I have used:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emotion@9.2.12/dist/emotion.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.5.10/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-input-autosize@2.2.1/dist/react-input-autosize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-select@2.1.2/dist/react-select.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Select component works absolutely fine for me. But Creatable Select doesn't work.
I tried some links for CreatableSelect also. Below is my overall Script :

````
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      //links for Select

      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emotion@9.2.12/dist/emotion.umd.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.5.10/prop-types.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-input-autosize@2.2.1/dist/react-input-autosize.min.js"> 
      </script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-select@2.1.2/dist/react-select.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

     //links for CreatableSelect

     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-select@3.1.0/dist/react-select.cjs.min.js"></script> 
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-select@3.1.0/creatable/dist/react- select.cjs.dev.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-select@3.1.0/creatable/dist/react- select.browser.esm.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-select@3.1.0/creatable/dist/react- select.browser.cjs.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-select@3.1.0/creatable/dist/react- select.cjs.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-select@3.1.0/creatable/dist/react-select.cjs.prod.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-select@3.1.0/creatable/dist/react-select.esm.min.js"></script>

      <title>Using React</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script type="text/babel">


      const options = [
        { value: 'A', label: 'A' },
        { value: 'B', label: 'B' },
        { value: 'C', label: 'C' }
      ];

      class App extends React.Component {
        state = {
          selected: null,
        }
        handleChange = (selected) => {
          this.setState({ selected });
        }
        render() {
          return (
            <div>
            <Select
              value={this.state.selected}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              options={options}
            />
            <CreatableSelect
              value={this.state.selected}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              options={options}
            />
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#root"))
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>```

How can I make CreatableSelect work? I am kinda noob so excuse any silly mistake and questions.
````